# Config for WCF MSMQ in workgroup mode

Tags: wcf, msmq, configuration-files

In trying to deploy a service I have found that it won't start because MSMQ is in workgroup mode. I have created a private queue instead and changed the config files to refer to it, but the WCF service host refuses to start with this message:

> Binding validation failed because the binding's MsmqAuthenticationMode property is set to WindowsDomain but MSMQ is installed with Active Directory integration disabled.

Can anyone tell me how to specify workgroup mode in the config file? The information I find in MSDN is all about modifying the setting in code, and makes no mention of how to specify this in the config file.

In the config file that I have, the bindings tag is empty (`<bindings />`) yet the service endpoint specifies `binding="netMsmqBinding"` which I imagine means a default configuration is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set anonymous integration authentication on the queue. [Look at this kb on why and how](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;952570).

In the [msdn there is a good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx) of working with workgroup mode. Note that the example use transactional queue. So you will have to make your queue transactional. This can be done only when creating the queue.

Post your code and config so we can comment on them.

Comment: My queue is already transactional for the reasons you mention. I sorted this out last night but your answer is a good one and the two links you provide are excellent so thank you.

Comment: Anyone interested in other good material on this topic should obtain a copy of Essential Windows Communication Foundation by Resnick, Crane and Bowen.

Comment: When I try and follow the notes in the KB article, trying to select the Security tab, I get the error ... The operation is not supported for Message Queuing installed in workgroup mode

Answer (score 4):

When we faced the issue
`<security mode="None">` worked in the test environment.

During final delivery , even that didn't work.. Finally this one worked

```
<security>
<transport
msmqAuthenticationMode="None"
msmqProtectionLevel="None"/>
</security>
```

Comment: So your solution to fixing security issues is to turn off security?  Brilliant!

Comment: This is great. Security mode=none worked, but then it stopped working for no easily discernible reason. Your solution really helped.